# OCR software/application that transforms hand-written code to digitally-written code

Tags: image-processing, programming, ocr, text-processing, source-code

What I am looking for is a software/application that takes a source code written by hand on a piece of paper and converts it to digital code in a clean, tidy, and orderly fashion. I do not want just an image-to-text type of OCR, but one that converts hand-written code to digitally-written code. I apologize in advance if my question has already been asked, but I am curious about this, as I like to write code on paper for practicing.

Comment: Do you have any sample images of your handwriting? What you're looking for is called ICR

Comment: Thank you for replying! Here is my handwriting -> https://imgur.com/tzIJFpz
It would be most convenient if the tool could detect different styles of handwriting. Is there by chance a piece of software that implements ICR but focuses primarily on code? Thanks in advance.